# MassTransit StateMachineSagaTestHarness - double message consumption

Tags: masstransit

I have a problem with `InMemoryTestHarness` and state machine saga. It looks like each published message are consumed twice by saga. If message are sent (not published) the problem does not occur. The problem started when I changed `CorrelationId` to custom field - `ProcessId`. Below simplified example exposing the problem.

Saga definition:

```cs
    public class MySaga : MassTransitStateMachine<MySagaState>
    {
        public State InProgress { get; private set; }

        public Event<StartProcess> StartProcess { get; private set; }
        public Event<ProcessStageFinished> StageFinished { get; private set; }
        public Event<ProcessFinished> ProcessFinished { get; private set; }


        public MySaga()
        {
            InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

            Event(() => StartProcess, e => e
                .CorrelateBy(i => i.ProcessId, x => x.Message.ProcessId)
                .SelectId(x => NewId.NextGuid()));

            Event(() => StageFinished, e => e
                .CorrelateBy(i => i.ProcessId, x => x.Message.ProcessId)
                .SelectId(x => NewId.NextGuid()));

            Event(() => ProcessFinished, e => e
                .CorrelateBy(i => i.ProcessId, x => x.Message.ProcessId)
                .SelectId(x => NewId.NextGuid()));

            Initially(
                When(StartProcess)
                    .Then(x => x.Instance.ProcessId = x.Data.ProcessId)
                    .TransitionTo(InProgress)
                );

            During(InProgress,
                When(StageFinished)
                    .Then(x => x.Instance.Stage++)
                );

            During(InProgress,
                When(ProcessFinished)
                    .Finalize()
                );
        }
    }

    public class MySagaState : SagaStateMachineInstance, ISagaVersion
    {
        public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
        public int Version { get; set; }
        public string ProcessId { get; set; }
        public string CurrentState { get; set; }
        public int Stage { get; set; }
    }

    public record StartProcess(Guid CorrelationId, string ProcessId) : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
    {
    }

    public record ProcessStageFinished(Guid CorrelationId, string ProcessId) : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
    {
    }

    public record ProcessFinished(Guid CorrelationId, string ProcessId) : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
    {
    }
```

And the xUnit test:

```cs
    public class MySagaTests
    {
        InMemoryTestHarness Harness { get; }
        IStateMachineSagaTestHarness<MySagaState, MySaga> SagaHarness { get; }

        public MySagaTests()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(config =>
                {
                    config.AddSagaStateMachine<MySaga, MySagaState>(sagaConfig =>
                        {
                            sagaConfig.UseConcurrentMessageLimit(1);
                            sagaConfig.UseInMemoryOutbox();
                        })
                       .InMemoryRepository();

                    config.AddSagaStateMachineTestHarness<MySaga, MySagaState>();
                });

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);

            Harness = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();
            Harness.OnConfigureInMemoryReceiveEndpoint += config =>
            {
                config.ConfigureSagas(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBusRegistrationContext>());
            };

            SagaHarness = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IStateMachineSagaTestHarness<MySagaState, MySaga>>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task TestMySaga()
        {
            string processId = "newProcessId";
            var correlationId = NewId.NextGuid();

            await Harness.Start();

            try
            {
                await Harness.Bus.Publish(new StartProcess(correlationId, processId));

                Assert.True(await Harness.Published.Any<StartProcess>());
                Assert.True(await Harness.Consumed.Any<StartProcess>());
                Assert.True(await SagaHarness.Consumed.Any<StartProcess>());
                Assert.Equal(1, SagaHarness.Sagas.Count());  // HERE should be only one saga created

                Assert.True(await SagaHarness.Created.Any(s => s.ProcessId == processId && s.CurrentState == "InProgress"));

                await Harness.Bus.Publish(new ProcessStageFinished(correlationId, processId));

                Assert.True(await Harness.Published.Any<ProcessStageFinished>());
                Assert.True(await Harness.Consumed.Any<ProcessStageFinished>());
                Assert.True(await SagaHarness.Consumed.Any<ProcessStageFinished>());
                var saga = SagaHarness.Sagas.Select(s => s.ProcessId == processId).FirstOrDefault()?.Saga;
                Assert.NotNull(saga);
                Assert.Equal(1, saga.Stage); // HERE stage should by 1

                await Harness.Bus.Publish(new ProcessFinished(correlationId, processId));

                Assert.True(await Harness.Published.Any<ProcessFinished>());
                Assert.True(await Harness.Consumed.Any<ProcessFinished>());
                Assert.True(await SagaHarness.Consumed.Any<ProcessFinished>());

                Assert.True(await SagaHarness.Sagas.Any(s => s.ProcessId == processId && s.CurrentState == "Final"));
            }
            finally
            {
                await Harness.Stop();
            }

        }
    }
```

I have tried it on simple in-memory bus configuration and on RabbitMQ. On both configuration it works fine. Messages are consumed twice only within `InMemoryTestHarness`.

Do you have any suggestions what should be fixed? At first glance it looks like a wrong behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, remove this line – you're configuring the saga on two separate endpoints.

```
Harness.OnConfigureInMemoryReceiveEndpoint += config =>
{
    config.ConfigureSagas(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBusRegistrationContext>());
};
```

Comment: Great. It helped. But now to pass the test I need to add some delays after each publish operation - like this: `await Task.Delay(100);`  Is it correct?

Comment: And one more thing. How currently can I send command to test saga? `Harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(new StartProcess(correlationId, processId))` does not work.

Comment: Call `Publish` instead of `Send`? Also, have you watched [Season 2](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx8uyNNs1ri1UA_Nerr7Ej3g9nT2PxbbH) of the MassTransit series on YouTube? It's all about state machines and unit testing. The [Sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Library) is extensive and shows how to use `Exists`, etc. to verify saga progress. Task.Delay in the unit test is a fail.

Comment: Thanks. Sample explains a lot. I've reorganized the test and now it looks and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After [@Chris Patterson] response I've reorganized the test. Maybe it will help somebody, reorganized test below:

```cs
    public class MySagaTests
    {
        InMemoryTestHarness Harness { get; }
        IStateMachineSagaTestHarness<MySagaState, MySaga> SagaHarness { get; }

        public MySagaTests()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(config =>
                {
                    config.AddSagaStateMachine<MySaga, MySagaState>(sagaConfig =>
                        {
                            sagaConfig.UseConcurrentMessageLimit(1);
                            sagaConfig.UseInMemoryOutbox();
                        })
                       .InMemoryRepository();

                    config.AddSagaStateMachineTestHarness<MySaga, MySagaState>();
                });

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);

            Harness = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();

            SagaHarness = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IStateMachineSagaTestHarness<MySagaState, MySaga>>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task TestMySaga()
        {
            string processId = "newProcessId";
            var correlationId = NewId.NextGuid();

            await Harness.Start();

            try
            {
                await Harness.Bus.Publish(new StartProcess(correlationId, processId));

                var sagaExists = (await SagaHarness.Exists(s => s.ProcessId == processId, x => x.InProgress)).Any();
                Assert.True(sagaExists, "Saga not exists");


                await Harness.Bus.Publish(new ProcessStageFinished(correlationId, processId));

                sagaExists = (await SagaHarness.Exists(s => s.ProcessId == processId && s.Stage == 1, x => x.InProgress)).Any();
                Assert.True(sagaExists, "Saga not exists");


                await Harness.Bus.Publish(new ProcessFinished(correlationId, processId));

                sagaExists = (await SagaHarness.Exists(s => s.ProcessId == processId, x => x.Final)).Any();
                Assert.True(sagaExists, "Saga not exists");
            }
            finally
            {
                await Harness.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```